# Massive.Sqlite.cs -- Prototype fails because there is no COLUMN_NAME; Fix using PRAGMA table_info?

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, massive

I having playing around with Rob Connery's Massive.Sqlite and I have a problem when the Prototype property is called: gets the schema base on this SQL sentence

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' and name = @0
```

Where @0 is the name of the table. Now, using the results from that query it tries to create an Expando set with the DB's defaults and, to do so, tries to access a property in the set named **COLUMN_NAME** which do not exists in the set (the columns there are:  type, name, tbl_name, rootpage, sql).

So I thought that I could fix it using a SQLite Pragma:

```
PRAGMA table_info('table_name');
```

But that did not worked either, this time because I get **no results** when the pragma executes.

Is there something I am missing? Do I have to active the pragma in the connection string? Is there a better way to solve this?

Or maybe I am just facing the problem with the wrong solution.

Thanks for your answers!

**Technical Notes:**

- Using System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.66.0 from Nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the Sqlite Schema detection is broken in Massive. It's already reported on github [issue#86](https://github.com/robconery/massive/issues/86) but the fix hasn't been applied.

I've just created a pull request with the fix: https://github.com/robconery/massive/pull/122 you can get the code from there or from the main [massive repository](https://github.com/robconery/massive) after it's merged.